# Overwrite input in php

Tags: php

I'd like to upload an image and resize it in php. I'm using this input to upload:

```
 <td><form action="uploadpic.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
        <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image" />
        <input name = "button" type = "button" id = "button" 
                          value = "Küldés" onclick="subm(this.form,'_blank');">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function subm(f,newtarget){
f.submit();
}
</script>
```

And here is what I'm doing in the uploadpic.php file:

```
$target_path = "images/clients/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['user_image']['name']); 

function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);

echo "original width ". $width." height ". $height;

$r = $width / $height;
if ($crop) {
    if ($width > $height) {
        $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
    } else {
        $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
    }
    $newwidth = $w;
    $newheight = $h;
} else {
    if ($w/$h > $r) {
        $newwidth = $h*$r;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        $newheight = $w/$r;
        $newwidth = $w;
    }
}
 echo "new width ". $newwidth." height ". $newheight;
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

return $dst;
}

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['user_image']['name']). 
"Image has been uploaded";

$_FILES['user_image'] = resize_image($target_path, 50, 50);

echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['user_image']['name']). 
" Image has been resized";

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['name'], $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['user_image']['name']). 
"   Resized image has been uploaded";
}else{
echo "  Resized not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES['user_image']['error'];
}

$image_name = 'alma';
$_SESSION['image_name']= 'alma';

} else{
echo "Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES['user_image']['error'];
}
```

This works until I trying to overwrite the `user_image` input. So what I'd like to do is upload the image resize it and upload the resized image. As you can see I'm trying to overwrite the `user_image` input with this line: 
`$_FILES['user_image'] = resize_image($target_path, 50, 50);`

It not works so I'd like to ask how can I overwrite it and upload it to the server?

Comment: Do you understand that `$_FILES['user_image']` is __array__, while result returnted by `resize_image` is __resource__ (which is __NOT__ array)?

Comment: Thank you. And have you any idea how to do it?

Comment: `imagejpeg`, `imagepng` functions will help

Comment: You can simply put it in a variable and that should do the trick. What I don't understand is the resize_image method... Shouldn't you send the $_FILES['user_image'] as a parameter?

Comment: @Nick Could you please show me how to do that? I'm new in php and I don't really understand how to put it in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using this great php library [Resize Image Class With PHP](http://www.paulund.co.uk/resize-image-class-php).

This is the relevant parts of my code that may help you:

```
<?php 
.
.
.
.
require_once('ResizeImage.php');
if(isset($_FILES['photoFile']) && $_FILES['photoFile']['error'] == 0){

 $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['photoFile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

 if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
  $response = json_encode(array("error" => "true","message" => "The image has the wrong extention"));
  echo $response;
  exit;
}
/*generate unique filename*/
$t=time();
$x=$_FILES['photoFile']['name'];
$name=md5($x.$t);

/*Moves the uploaded file*/
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photoFile']['tmp_name'], '../uploads/original/'.$name.'.'.$extension)){
  $firstimage = '../uploads/original/'.$name.'.'.$extension;
  $secondimage = '../uploads/original/'.$name.'.'.$extension;

  $small2 = compress($firstimage, $firstimage, 45);
  $resize = new ResizeImage($small2);
  unset($small2);
  $resize->resizeTo(250, 250, 'maxWidth');
  $resize->saveImage('../uploads/thumb/'.$name.'.jpg');
  unset($resize);

        //Compress & resize image large

  $large = compress($secondimage, $secondimage, 45);
  $resize2 = new ResizeImage($large);
  unset($large);
  $resize2->resizeTo(560, 560, 'maxWidth');
  $resize2->saveImage('../uploads/large/'.$name.'.jpg');
  unset($resize2);
  /*file location for database*/

  $fileThumb = "uploads/thumb/".$name.".jpg";
  $fileLarge = "uploads/large/".$name.".jpg";
  $response = saveDatabase($nombre,$apellido,$email,$pais,$ciudad,$mensaje,$fileThumb,$fileLarge,$ip);
  if ($response == 1) {
    $response = json_encode(array("error" => "false","message" => "Thanks"));
    echo $response;
  }else{
   $response = json_encode(array("error" => "true","message" => "unknown error "));
   echo $response;
 }

}
}

?>
```

First, we validate that $_FILES['photoFile'] does indeed exist and does not have errors, then we save it to a temporary operation, resize it, compress it and save it in a new location.

Home it helps

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Glad to help :)